# Комбинаторика и простые числа

Tags: javascript, комбинаторика, генерация-случайных-данных

`magicFunc([3,4])`- функция, которая принимает в качестве аргумента массив с цифрами.

Она проходит по числам от 1 до 1 000 000, которые состоят из цифр в переданном массиве (прим. 3 и 4) и проверяет простое ли число или нет. Если число простое, то оно возвращается в качестве результата, а если нет то возвращается false.

Пример:

```
magicFunc([3,4]) => 3343 
magicFunc([3,1]) => 13
magicFunc([2,8]) => false
```

Я пытался делать цикл до миллиона, но это на час, решил что так не пойдёт. Думаю нужно генерировать новые числа до 1 000 000, состоящие из цифр в массиве, и сразу проверять их на то, простые они или нет. Есть ли лучший вариант для решения подобной задачи или пойдёт и этот?

Comment: "magicFunc([3,4])  => 3343" - а почему не 43 или 3?

Comment: 3 - потому что должно вернуть число состоящее из всех чисел переданных в массиве, а вот почему не 43, 43 должно вернуть верно, мне ментор прислал что у должно вернуть 3343 а я и не проверил, но сейчас глянул действительно 43 подходит.

Comment: смысл вас менторить, если вы решать не будете, за вас все сделают?

Comment: пишите по делу, а смысл или нет, решать не вам. Если человек спрашивает, значит смысл есть.

Comment: @СергейСеменов возможно все комбинации лежат до 100 и смысла генерировать 1000000 нет, либо вам нужно уточнить формулировку

Comment: изменил код  добавил `число состоящее из всех чисел переданных в массиве`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

генерируем все возможные числа длиной 2, проверяем есть ли простые, если есть выводим первое простое число, если нет идём циклом наращивая длину чисел до 6 (до 1 000 000), добавлена проверка чтоб число состояло из комбинации всех чисел исходного массива

```js
function testPrime(arr) {
  var isPrime = false;
  for (var k = 0, number; number = arr[k++];) {
    number = +number.join(",").split(",").join("");
    var checkNumber = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number));
    for (i = 2; i <= checkNumber; i++)
      if (number % i == 0 && number != i) {
        isPrime = false;
        break
      } else isPrime = true;
    if (isPrime) return number
  }
  return false
}

function combinator(matrix) {
  return matrix.reduceRight(function(combination, x) {
    var result = [];
    x.forEach(function(a) {
      combination.forEach(function(b) {
        result.push([a].concat(b))
      })
    });
    return result
  })
}

function arrFilter(res, arr) {
  return res.filter(function(a) {
    return arr.every(function(b) {
      return !!~a.join(",").split(",").indexOf(b + "")
    })
  })
}

function magicFunc(arr) {
  var temp = arr.slice().sort();
  var res = combinator([temp.slice(), temp.slice()]);
  for (var i = 2; i < 8; i++)
    if (i >= arr.length) {
      var prime = arrFilter(res, temp); //фильтруем все числа на наличие всех цифр
      prime = testPrime(prime); //ищем первое простое
      if (prime) return prime; //если есть простое выводим результат
      res = combinator([res, temp.slice()]); //если нет увеличиваем длину чисел
    }
  return false
};
alert([magicFunc([1]), magicFunc([3, 4]), magicFunc([7, 1, 5]), magicFunc([8, 2])])
```

Comment: на этапе сборки числа-кандидата отбрасывать оканчивающиеся на 5, 0 или на чётную цифру. Ещё здорово оптимизировать, опираясь на [признаки делимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BA_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0_2)

Comment: @ Sergiks согласен, для оптимизации есть простор например если сумма всех цифр делится на 3, то и само число делится на 3

Comment: да-да, про делимость на 3 идёт вторым пунктом в признаках по ссылке – мне оч. понравилось лаконичностью, не знал/забыл : )